# row selection on row click but not on hyperlink click in one of the column in jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, datatable

i have my customer dataTable which has five columns. one column contains hyperlink. One of the column is checkbox.
i want when user clicks on the row, that row should be selected(which means row color should change and checkbox
should be selected). i can do it with below code snippet

```
 $("#customer").on('click', $.fn.getDataTablesClickHandler("#selectAll"));
 //where customer is the html div associated with dataTable and call the same function which gets triggered
 //on call of selectAll html element. Inside that function i toggle the class of row
```

It works great. But my problem is i dont want this to happen(i.e row seection)  on click of link inside one of the column.
how i can do this?So basically how can i restrict firing getDataTablesClickHandler on click of certain link in a cell or
on click on cell?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out, you want to check out which target is being clicked, and ignore it if it's an anchor tag.

```
$("#customer").on('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName == 'A')
        return;

    $.fn.getDataTablesClickHandler("#selectAll").apply(this);
});
```

Comment: Bryan your solution's last line  $.fn.getDataTablesClickHandler("#selectAll").apply(this) does not select the row?

Comment: You need to provide an example of your HTML to give you a better answer, I simply took what you did and it applied it to the context of #customer being a tr. You might be able to just get rid of the .apply(this)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

if customer is your table;

```
 $("#customer").on('click', 'tr', function(){
    if( !$(this).is('tr') )
        return;
    $.fn.getDataTablesClickHandler("#selectAll");
 });
```

Comment: Anil  your last line $.fn.getDataTablesClickHandler("#selectAll") is not working? i mean it does not select the row